# Cross account codepipeline using pull method

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, amazon-kms

I'm trying to create a cross account codepipeline and there is no appropriate document for this scenario.

1. AccounT - A has s3 bucket with yaml file
2. Account- B  Will have Codepipeline

Account B codepipeline should have  S3 as source in source stage from Account A and cloudformation deploy method in deploy stage. Can someone please help on what are the roles and other needs has to fulfilled to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that you need to make this work.

1. Your bucket needs to use a customer KMS key, not the default. This is because you can't grant permissions to another account to use the default key, meaning another account can't decrypt the data in the bucket. You need to grant permission in the key policy to allow the other account to decrypt using that key. Ideally not just to the entire account, but the role that is being used in your CodePipeline source step.
2. You have to grant access to the other account in your S3 bucket policy. Ideally not just to the entire account, but the role that is being used in your CodePipeline source step.

I have a [project](https://github.com/jasonwadsworth/AWS-CrossAccount-CrossRegion-Pipeline)  that does some of this using organizations. It isn't exactly what you want, in that the CodePipeline in my project lives in "AccountT" and the pipeline runs CloudFormation (or other things) run in "Account-B". So in my case only CloudFormation is reaching back to the bucket in "AccountT". I don't think it should be a big change to modify it to work the way you need it to work. My project is largely based off [this AWS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html).

Comment: Thank you Jason I was able to fix the issue with the help of the instructions you have provided. Thanks for taking time and rendering help to fix the issue.